# Using cancan to limit listing objects according to roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, cancan

In my abilities.rb I have

```
user ||= User.new
if user.has_role? :admin
  can :manage, :all
elsif user.has_role? :collaborator
  can :manage, Task, :user_id => user.id
else
  can :read, Task, :user_id => user.id
end
```

The issue is that, in TasksController, when I write this:

```
def index
    @taks = Task.all.order('created_at DESC')
end
```

When logged in as collaborator, it does not filter the listing of tasks:

> Task Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks"   ORDER BY created_at DESC

But, when I write this:

```
def index
    Task.all.order('created_at DESC')
end
```

When logged in as collaborator, It does filter:

> Task Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "tasks"  WHERE "tasks"."user_id" = 2

But does not order the listing! I don't understand why it behaves different, and how can I filter and order without adding extra logic in the controller?

I am using rails' '4.1.4', 'devise' '3.3.0', 'cancan' '1.6.10'.

Answer (score 0):

I've just came up with the following solution:

```
def index
  @tasks = Tasks.accessible_by(current_ability).all.order('created_at DESC')
end
```

It does filter and order:

> Task Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "tasks".* FROM "taks"  WHERE "tasks"."user_id" = 2  ORDER BY created_at DESC

For some reason, when calling with the current ability it works.